# Change phonegap android package name

Tags: android, cordova

so i've built phonegap 3.30 android app , and the package name of the app is com.IFDstudio.Janana but i want to change that to com.Jananamobile.Janana

how can i do that??
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open **app-root/www/config.xml**. Then you see where you have to make the changes :-) More information: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface_create_the_app